# I need to create an excel formula*

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a customer that has 90 day terms and they pay on the 1st and 15th of the month. I need a formula that I can plug into my reports that will reflect the day an invoice should be paid.  right now I just show the invoice date +90 which reflex my system due date and I am looking for a more accurate formula

Comment: So if the 90 days ended on the 13th would it be the 15th or the prior 1st?  What have you tried?  Can you show some examples and expected output?

Comment: so If the 90 days ends between the 1st and 15th its due the 14 if 15-31 due on the 1st of the next month.  Honestly I don't even know where to start. I know it has got to be an if than formula but I have a hard time with these especially when it comes to dates

Comment: The description in your comment is different from what's in your question, maybe a typo?  Do you mean if 90 days falls in the range 1-14 it's due on the 15th.  If it falls in the range 15-31 it's due the 1st of the next month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
=IF(DAY(A1+90)<15,EOMONTH(A1+90,-1)+15,EOMONTH(A1+90,0)+1)
```

[image]